# how to get the Bar Button Item from Split View Controller without rotating the device?

Tags: delegates, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am developering in iOS 5.1 and is pretty happy with these methods in UISplitViewControllerDelegate

```
splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController
splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem:
```

however, now I notice that these two methods will be only called when the device is rotating and thus the orientation changes. What I am trying to do is to segue(replace segue) my detail view controller to another one. In the new detail view controller, I will always hide the master view controller even in landscape and therefore I need the button.

Without the delegate being called of these two methods, how can I get the button?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding your master view controller even in landscape (by means of split view controller delegate), the `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` will be called, so you can safely put your code there.

Comment: this code is there , it gets called everytime but the menu button disappears in portrait mode on changing the viewcontroller